# ASP.Net Core & Docker - Project file does not exist

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have this Dockerfile

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install wget gnupg \
    git \
    unzip

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
WORKDIR /app
#EXPOSE 5001

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["mediere.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./mediere.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install wget gnupg \
    git \
    unzip

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
#RUN npm install zone.js@0.11.3 --save
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet build "mediere.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "mediere.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "mediere.dll"]
```

and running docker-compose up throws me this error:

```
 => ERROR [build 11/11] RUN dotnet build "mediere.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build                                 2.5s
------
 > [build 11/11] RUN dotnet build "mediere.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build:
#23 2.241 Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET
#23 2.241 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
#23 2.241
#23 2.245 MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
#23 2.245 Switch: mediere.csproj
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet build "mediere.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
```

and I don't see why.

I'm using a default ASP.Net core & Angular template from VS 2019 and I'm trying to dockerize it.

Here's the folder structure:
[image: photo]

why am I getting this error?

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're setting the current working directory to `/app` right before building the project:

```
WORKDIR /app
```

The project doesn't exist in that directory. There should be no need to have that line at all because the working directory before this instruction gets executed is the correct one.